# How to manage custome miltiple url in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I am trying to integrate url for multiple controllers/actions in different ways. Suppose I have two controllers site and product controller. I wish to get the value of correspondent controller, While pass different parameter in the url. I mean when I pass slug parameter it must fetch from site/pages and when I pass category parameter then it must fetch from product/view .

```
            '<category:>/<id:>' => 'product/view',
            '<category:>' => 'product/view',
            '<slug:>' => 'site/pages',
```

I have tried with above example and it works fine for category but 404 error occur on slug.

**EDIT**

This is how my rest of task looks.

Product Controller action

```
public function actionView($category, $id= null)
{        
    $category = Category::findOne(['slug' => $category]);
    // rest of work
}
```

And this is my createUrl params for product

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/product/view','category'=> 'handicraft-product', 'id'=> 'nepali-thanka-134']);
```

And I just want to access this action like
http://www.example.com/handicraft-product or
http://www.example.com/handicraft-product/nepali-thanka-134

Site Controller action

```
public function actionPages($slug)
    {        
        $model = $this->findByPageSlug($slug);
        return $this->render('pages',['model' => $model]);
    }
```

And this is my createUrl params for site's pages action

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/site/pages','slug' => 'terms-and-condition']);
```

And this is how I want to access this action like
http://www.example.com/terms-and-condition

How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the URLs must be a little different. How would Yii2 figure out that /bbbbbb should go to product/view and /aaaaaa should go to another page?

Comment: @Mihai P Yeah I exactly wish that..  I have updated my question, and waiting for your opinion. Anyway thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:
1) make the URL a little different. You could define them like this:

```
'category/<category:>' => 'product/view',
'page/<slug:>' => 'site/pages',
```

Depending on how you define the links they might actually help your SEO.
2) Create a custom URL manager rule to handle the text for both pages and categories. See here: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rule-classes

In the custom rule you can try finding the category URL and if you cannot then default to a page URL.

Comment: Yeah option1 is not  in my choice and I have tried option2 by extending yii\web\UrlRule and yii\web\UrlManager. But I can't get .. ;(  . Anyway waiting for desired solutions. Till that I am using option1 :)....